# Inserting datetime value into sql server table column

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm attempting to insert a `datetime('2013-08-30 19:05:00')` value into a SQL server database table column(smalldatetime) and the value stays "NULL" after the insert.

I'm doing this to 6 other columns that are the exact same type. What is this only occuring on one column? I've triple checked that the names of the columns are correct. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to make the sql column be timestamp timestamp default current_timestamp? Anyway your question is not specific enough, post the code, show us what's failing.

Comment: First idea would be to post your code, and give more details about the table.

Comment: Also check for triggers on the table.

Comment: @Martin - You were correct in saying to check the triggers,it was missing the new date column. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the situation is as you describe

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
S SMALLDATETIME NULL
)

INSERT INTO T 
VALUES('2013-08-30 19:05:00')

SELECT *
FROM T /*Returns NULL*/
```

There are only two ways I can think of that this can happen.

1) That is an ambiguous datetime format. Under the wrong session options this won't cast correctly and if you have some additional options `OFF` it will return `NULL` rather than raise an error (e.g.)

```
SET LANGUAGE Italian;
SET ansi_warnings OFF;
SET arithabort OFF; 

INSERT INTO T 
VALUES('2013-08-30 19:05:00')

SELECT *
FROM T /*NULL inserted*/
```

2) You may have missed the column out in an `INSTEAD OF` trigger, or have an `AFTER` trigger that actually sets the value back to `NULL`.